# Can I have an ApiController action return ViewModel option?

Tags: f#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on converting the "new Project" template of a Single Page App from C# to F#, and I had a question: can controllers return a `SomeViewModel option` (or a `Task<SomeViewModel option>`)?

Here's my view model declarations:

```
module ViewModels =
    [<CLIMutable>]         
    type ExternalLoginViewModel = 
        { Name:string; 
          Url: string; 
          State:string }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    type UserInfoViewModel =
        { UserName : string;
          HasRegistered : bool;
          LoginProvider : string}

    [<CLIMutable>]
    type UserLoginInfoViewModel =
        { LoginProvider : string;
          ProviderKey : string }

    [<CLIMutable>]
    type ManageInfoViewModel =
        { LocalLoginProvider : string;
          UserName : string;
          Logins : seq<UserLoginInfoViewModel>;
          ExternalLoginProviders : seq<ExternalLoginViewModel>}
```

And here's the relevant action (in AccountController.fs)

```fs
// GET api/Account/ManageInfo?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
[<Route("ManageInfo")>]
member x.GetManageInfo (returnUrl: string, generateState: bool) =
    async {
        let! user = userManager.FindByIdAsync(x.User.Identity.GetUserId())
                    |> Async.AwaitTask
        if user = null
        then return None
        else
            let logins = 
                seq {
                    for linkedAccount in user.Logins 
                        do yield 
                            { LoginProvider = linkedAccount.LoginProvider; 
                              ProviderKey = linkedAccount.ProviderKey }
                     if user.PasswordHash <> null 
                        then yield 
                            { LoginProvider = localLoginProvider; 
                              ProviderKey = user.UserName }
                 }
            return Some 
                { LocalLoginProvider = localLoginProvider;
                  UserName = user.UserName;
                  Logins = logins;
                  ExternalLoginProviders = 
                      x.GetExternalLogins(returnUrl, generateState)}
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

For reference, here's the C# implementations:

```cs
public class ExternalLoginViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class ManageInfoViewModel
{
    public string LocalLoginProvider { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<UserLoginInfoViewModel> Logins { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ExternalLoginViewModel> ExternalLoginProviders { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfoViewModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public bool HasRegistered { get; set; }

    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
}

public class UserLoginInfoViewModel
{
    public string LoginProvider { get; set; }

    public string ProviderKey { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// GET api/Account/ManageInfo?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
[Route("ManageInfo")]
public async Task<ManageInfoViewModel> GetManageInfo(string returnUrl, bool generateState = false)
{
    IdentityUser user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    if (user == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    List<UserLoginInfoViewModel> logins = new List<UserLoginInfoViewModel>();

    foreach (IdentityUserLogin linkedAccount in user.Logins)
    {
        logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
        {
            LoginProvider = linkedAccount.LoginProvider,
            ProviderKey = linkedAccount.ProviderKey
        });
    }

    if (user.PasswordHash != null)
    {
        logins.Add(new UserLoginInfoViewModel
        {
            LoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
            ProviderKey = user.UserName,
        });
    }

    return new ManageInfoViewModel
    {
        LocalLoginProvider = LocalLoginProvider,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Logins = logins,
        ExternalLoginProviders = GetExternalLogins(returnUrl, generateState)
    };
}
```

Comment: I added a response for a simple experiment.

Comment: Is that MVC 5? It looks like Web API to me...

Comment: Alright, you got me, it's WebAPI 2, that shipped with MVC 5.

Comment: In which case I think the answer you provided yourself actually answers the question pretty well (+1) :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried a simple test: two cases from the default ValuesController.

First case, using BadResult and Ok methods:

```
[<RoutePrefix("api2/values")>]
type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    let values = [|"value1";"value2"|]

    /// Gets all values.
    [<Route("")>]
    member x.Get() = values

    /// Gets the value with index id.
    [<Route("{id:int}")>]
    member x.Get(id) : IHttpActionResult =
        if id > values.Length - 1 then
            x.BadRequest() :> _
        else x.Ok(values.[id]) :> _
```

output:

- /api2/values/1 - 200 - "value2"
- /api2/values/3 - 400

Second Case, using string option

```
[<RoutePrefix("api2/values")>]
type ValuesController() =
    inherit ApiController()
    let values = [|"value1";"value2"|]

    /// Gets all values.
    [<Route("")>]
    member x.Get() = values

    /// Gets the value with index id.
    [<Route("{id:int}")>]
    member x.Get(id) =
        if id > values.Length - 1 then
            None
        else Some(values.[id])
```

output:

- /api2/values/1 - 200 - {"Case":"Some","Fields":["value2"]}
- /api2/values/3 - 200 - null

So effectively, here's two different methods to handle responses. The out-of-box serialization of the Some case is a little verbose, but it works.

Comment: While it works using options, I wouldn't go that route, as the output is non-idiomatic from an HTTP perspective. The first option is much better, although the correct response would be 404.